# Need to Pass multiple results from query back into one memo cell

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have been all over the web for days searching for a way to accomplish the following, and I am praying some experts can help me figure it out!  I have a client that wants to dynamically build a shipping "approval" email by pulling various text statements in, based on the results of queries.  The shipping details will be in one table, and the statements will be in another table. There could be multiple statements returned for each shipment (e.g. several training statements, several general statements).  Each of these statements needs to be added into a memo cell (created to hold each type of statement) which will then be pulled into the email template for that shipment.  The table structures are as follows.

```
Shipment_Table
*ID
*Shipment Type - Query Criteria 
*Material Category - Query Criteria 
*Permit Required - Query Criteria 
*General Statement (memo field to hold all general statements that match criteria)
*Training Statement (memo field to hold all training statements that match criteria)
*Approval Statement (memo field to hold all approval statements that match criteria)

Statement_Table
*Statement Type (e.g. General, Training, Approval)
*Shipment Type - Query Criteria 
*Material Category - Query Criteria 
*Permit Required - Query Criteria
```

I successfully have a query (titled StatementSearch) that joins the two and pulls in the correct statements. I can't figure out how to take the multiple query results and append them into the memo cells for the shipment.

The code that has come close is below.  It seems to correctly run my query and return the results, but is not putting the results into the memo field for my test record (ID =1 just to test the code, it will eventually run off of a form and the statements will generate off the click of a button).

I hope this isn't too confusing!

---

```
Option Explicit

Function StatementUpdate()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rstStatements As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstCBG As DAO.Recordset

Set dbs = CurrentDb()
Set rstStatements = dbs.OpenRecordset("StatementSearch")
Set rstCBG = dbs.OpenRecordset("select [St_General]from
[Cross_Border_Grid_Table] where [ID]= 1")

rstCBG.MoveFirst
'loop through each record in the CBG that matches select query
Do Until rstCBG.EOF
    rstStatements.MoveFirst
    Do Until rstStatements.EOF
        rstCBG.Edit
        rstCBG![St_General] = rstStatements
        rstCBG.Update
    rstStatements.MoveNext
    Loop
    rstCBG.MoveNext
    Loop

rstCBG.Close
rstStatements.Close

Set rstStatements = Nothing
Set rstCBG = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing

Debug.Print "Done"

End Function
```

Comment: not sure what you are looking for: if you want to add more string to an existing field you should "ADD" and not overwrite. something like rstCBG![St_General] =  rstCBG![St_General] & VBnewline & rstStatements

Comment: Thanks for chiming in!  So far my code isn't working to even overwrite.  The query returns two statements and I can't get any of them into the [St_General] field in the rstCBG table.  I am struggling with the syntax to loop through and add the multiple results.  Thank you for the help on Add vs. overwrite...that would have been my next struggle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your loops

```
Dim concStatement as String
rstCBG.MoveFirst

Do Until rstCBG.EOF
    concStatement = ""
    rstStatements.MoveFirst
    Do Until rstStatements.EOF
        concStatement = concStatement & vbCrLF & rstStatements(0)
        rstStatements.MoveNext
    Loop

    rstCBG.Edit
    rstCBG![St_General] = concStatement 
    rstCBG.Update
    rstCBG.MoveNext
Loop
```

I assume, your "StatementSearch" is a query that finds all statements according to ID=1. If there is more than one recordsets "rstCBG", you have to requery rstStatements in each loop step.

**EDIT:**

Changed rstStatement to rstStatement(0).

Also `rstStatements(0)` could be wrong: Change index = 0 to the index of the field in your query. As stated, the query is not visible in your question, so I do not know the right index number.

Comment: Thanks!  I feel like I'm getting closer!  do you have any idea why I would be getting a "Compile error: Type mismatch" on rstStatements in the concStatement = concStatement & vbCrLF & rstStatements line?

Comment: My query is as follows:

Comment: SELECT Statement_Table.Statement
FROM Statement_Table LEFT JOIN Cross_Border_Grid_Table ON (Statement_Table.[Permit Required] = Cross_Border_Grid_Table.[Permit Required]) AND (Statement_Table.[Material Category] = Cross_Border_Grid_Table.[Material Category]) AND (Statement_Table.[Shipment Type] = Cross_Border_Grid_Table.[Shipment Type])
WHERE (((Statement_Table.[Approval Category])='General Information'));

Comment: Since `Statement_Table.Statement` is the only field queried, `rstStatements(0)` should work

Comment: You're welcome. Be aware that this query will probably need an update where you filter out the right statements from an ID. I can not see the dependencies of the whole application, so it is just a lucky guess. BTW: Thank you comments will probably be deleted by SO. If possible, check correct answers instead.